# Is there a way to add forced empty values to columns on the sink side in a copy data flow?

Tags: json, csv, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON file  as my data source. I am trying to convert this file to a .csv format. The sink will contain several empty columns I would like to add. The problem is, it seems I am unable to add a column which does not exist in the source JSON file. I have tried several different sink types (database table, csv, etc.) I always seem to get a mapping issue, where I cannot add the empty columns to the schema on the sink side. Is there a way to accomplish this:

[image]

[image: Working flow for single JSON]

[image: can't see input columns to build expression]

Comment: Update, I am able to map the data to a database table without issue. I would, however like to see a method to map directly to a flat file. Seems silly there isn't a simple way to do this. Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason.Actually copy activity has some limitations so i'm afraid you can't add a column which does not exist in the source side.Because this is illegal in copy activity.Please see the [error conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping) in copy activity:

- Source data store query result does not have a column name that is
  specified in the input dataset "structure" section.
- Sink data store (if with pre-defined schema) does not have a column
  name that is specified in the output dataset "structure" section.
- Either fewer columns or more columns in the "structure" of sink
  dataset than specified in the mapping.
- Duplicate mapping.

However,your needs could be implemented in Data Flow Activity which is similar to copy activity.Please get an idea of [Mapping Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping).You could use [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern) to create some empty columns which does not exist in the source data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this.

Comment: @JasonHopper Sure,any concern just let me know.

Comment: Jay, I was able to add the columns using derived task as you suggest. Thank you!

Comment: I do have one more question. I want to add dynamic file name based on column in my source+date mashup. No matter what I do, it seems the visual expression editor cannot see the data flow columns anywhere downstream, and hence the data cannot be used in the editor. Any ideas? The input schema shows empty in the editor (see above).